# Why are my keyframes stacking through the animation instead of moving frame by frame? (2D animation)

Tags: keyframes, 2d

This is my first time using blender and I’m working on a 2D animation but my computer was having difficulties and now all of my keyframes stay on screen and stack together, like for example I used an interpolation sequence and every breakdown is displayed on screen together rather than moving frame by frame. Is there some setting I could change to fix this?

Comment: What you are describing sounds like some kind of onion skinning feature. But I don't know Blender to have one. Someone please confirm if it does.

Comment: Blender does have an onion skin feature, which I had been using throughout the animation but now each keyframe stays on screen for almost the entire animation,  adding on top of one another (when I was originally animating I would use additive animation where I built on the previous frame and erased a few things, now it seems like everything I erased is staying on screen and stacking on top of one another). The problem started after I merged two layers and then my computer started glitching out.

Comment: What kind of layers? What version of Blender are you using?

Comment: Grease pencil, I’m using version 2.83